# How to create a Zoom on images on my .Net webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, zooming

I need to create a Zoom method on an image on my webpage where the image diplayed on the screen can be zoomed in by pressing a '+' button or zoomed out by pressing a '-' button.

Has anyone already found a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need such things. You can have more Jquery stuffs. I have worked on this.
http://www.starplugins.com/cloudzoom. Googling can give you more closure resultsets.

Answer (score 0):

On your .NET web page, you can use [Deep Zoom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).